# MongoDB returning latest documents from each category in one find statement?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Let's say I have a `status` and a `createdAt` field and a few other fields like `title` and `content`.

The status field can take on `open, closed, or pending` values.

I basically want to return the 5 latest documents from **each status value** in one find statement. Is this possible? Also, can this be done without `aggregate`?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
db.collectionName.find().sort({"_id":-1}).limit(5).pretty()
```

It return's latest five documents

Comment: I want the 5 latest documents from each status value, I've bolded it in the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Bad news: that's not possible with basic queries. For a simple reason: you can only limit on a complete result set. So even when you use a logic `OR` on the status field, the first twenty documents of your result set may well all be of status "closed". When you apply whatever limit on this result set, up to the first twenty documents will have the status "closed".

I am not even sure wether this can be done easily with aggregation, I have to think about that.

Comment: Yup, which is why I thought i'd leave it up to the mongodb experts. I'm pretty sure it can be done with aggregates, so if you can find a solution that has uses aggregates, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Markus right. Unfortunatelly, it's not possible to do it in *one* aggregation query due to the lack of *slice* operation in a *project* phase of an aggregation pipeline.

It means, that you could easily group documents by status like this:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([        
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$status",
            "docs": { "$push": "$title" }
        }}
    ]);
```

BUT there is not way to slice resulting sub-arrays during this aggregation. This feature was [requested](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6074), but not implemented yet.

You could slice it after aggregation using a separate command. Or you always have an option to use [Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).

Another option is to iterate over statuses in your application and query documents by each status. I would go with this solution in your scenario, because you have just 3 different statuses. It means only 3 queries. It is not fatal(especially if you have index on status field).